# Email validation using js

Tags: jquery, regex

I was following the below link for email validations using js:
http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/validate-email-address-using-jquery.html

If I put `xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx` its giving valid email which is correct.
If I put `xxxx+xxxx@xxx.xxx` its giving invalid email but I want this to be valid.

For that I had added `/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i` as the regular expression. But it is not firing validation for `xxxxxx@`. Can some one please give some clue.

Comment: Watch your tags, they were completely wrong. You may optionally provide a fiddle for that regex, e.g via http://refiddle.com/

Comment: That regex works fine for me, for both email addresses.

Comment: What do you mean by "not firing validation"? xxxxx@ simply doesn't match the regex provided

Comment: You should probably include the whole validation function you are using, as stated your regex is right, and since it is 'not firing' probably means something is wrong with the function rather than the regex.

Comment: Nowadays you can use `<input type="email">` to win this type of validation for free from the browser. It is a valid (plus easier to implement and more robust) option if you don't need to support older browsers

Comment: @BartexR - By "not firing validation" I mean that if I put xxxx@, then its accepting the email. The system should tell me that the email is invalid. Basically I don't want any validation for xxxx+xxxx.xxx but I want the validation for xxxx@x

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function validateEmail(sEmail) {
>
>    var filter = /^([\w-\.\+]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
>    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
>        return true;
>    }
>    else {
>        return false;
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:-

**Case-1:- Check Valid Email With Allow Empty Value**

```
function JSTestValidEmail(fsEmail) {
    var lsRegex = new RegExp(/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/);
    if (fsEmail != "") {
        if (!lsRegex.test(fsEmail)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Case-2:- Check Valid Email With Not Allow Empty Value**

```
function JSTestValidEmail(fsEmail) {
    var lsRegex = new RegExp(/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/);
    if (fsEmail != "") {
        if (lsRegex.test(fsEmail)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

if(!reg.test(objEmailTxtField.value)){
    alert("false");
}
else{
    alert("true");
}
```